# How to manipulate current element's parent, sibling, next and previous elements using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Following is the html code where I have attached `$scope` properties and values to controls as:

[image]

And this is the click function where I am changing images path on image clicked as:

```
$scope.ratingClick = function(e)
{
    $log.info(e.currentTarget.src); //Current element src
    $log.info(e.next().src);        //Next Element Src
    $log.info(e.prev().src);        //Prev Element Src
}
```

On each image click I have to change image URL for current, previous and next element. But I am able to get only current image URL which has being clicked.

How to get parent, next, previous and sibling elements using current element in AngularJS?

Comment: manipulating dom in controller is not advisable in Angular. Probably you can change ur code to directive and manipulate the dom in link function

Comment: @selvassn, How could I do that?

Answer (score 3):

`e` refers to the click event, and usually `e.target` holds the reference to the actual related element (I'm not sure what's the difference between that and `currentTarget` is)

You could use `e.target` like this:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
  ];
  $scope.logPrevNext = function (e) {
    console.log('prev', angular.element(e.target).prev().text());
    console.log('current', angular.element(e.target).text());
    console.log('next', angular.element(e.target).next().text());
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="logPrevNext($event)">
    Item #{{$index}}
  </div>
</div>
```

However, I strongly recommend against doing it this way - an alternative, more "angular-y" way would be something like this:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.itemStrNo = [
    'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six'
  ];
  $scope.items = [
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
  ];
  $scope.logPrevNext = function (idx) {
    $scope.itemStrNo[idx-1] = 'BOOM!';
    $scope.itemStrNo[idx] = 'SNIKT!';
    $scope.itemStrNo[idx+1] = 'POW!';
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="logPrevNext($index)">
    Item no. {{itemStrNo[$index]}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Of course, you can use an array for the images (as I used), or a function, or a regular var... Whatever you choose. But manipulating elements directly in angular is bad, especially since 2 way binding might override your change on the next digest cycle.

Comment: @casrag, It is part of ng-repeat. So, if I do like above you have mention then it would change image source in all rows.

Comment: The ng-repeat is just my example since you didn't provide other context - regardless, it shouldn't change too much - the basic logic still holds. What is different in your code that would fail to make this work?

Comment: The point of the answer is: don't modify the element itself, instead, expose a controller variable that will be used in the image source, and modify that. This is a good example of 2 way binding.